# Iterating a dictionary while modifying it concurrently

Tags: python, multithreading, dictionary, cpython

I have a piece of code where I would like to iterate through a Python dictionary while it is being modified from a separate thread. Specifically, the other thread may: 1) Add new keys, 2) Modify the values in existing keys. It will *not* delete any keys.

This code should also be as performant as possible. It is okay if we miss the newer keys when iterating.

My code currently looks like this:

```
### THREAD 1
def add_data(my_dict, key, state):
  if key not in my_dict:
    # Adding of new keys is infrequent, but frequent enough that it causes errors sometimes.
    my_dict[key] = SomeClass()
  my_dict[key].change_state(state)

### THREAD 2
def get_data(my_dict):
  return [v.transform_in_some_way() for k, v in my_dict.items()]
```

This code occasionally throws `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`.

I have since changed the code in Thread 2 to be like this:

```
### THREAD 2
def get_data(my_dict):
  return [my_dict[k].transform_in_some_way() for k in list(my_dict.keys())]
```

In simple tests, this code has worked well, and I no longer see the `RuntimeError` - but I am not sure if I've truly fixed the problem, or if I've only made it less frequent. Which is it?

---

If this is not an appropriate fix - is there any way to iterate a Python dictionary while adding keys to it concurrently, and avoid extra synchronization? is there any thread-safe way to get a list of dictionary keys?

Comment: You should not modify a dictionary while iterating over it. The exceptions you see are just the first of many problems you will encounter with that design. Organize your code in a different way (I cannot say exactly which way, because I cannot even imagine what you are trying to do).

Comment: The thread that iterates is used to send periodic updates about the system. The thread that modifies is performing work, and changing the state of the system.

Comment: For that purpose, I would use a queue. Items would be added to the queue by one thread to request a task to be done. It would then be read (and removed from it) my another thread, which does the tasks.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are trying to write to the dict while reading it (looping through the keys). By doing `list(my_dict.keys())` you are "freezing" the keys (by creating a separate instance) so it no longer throws an error, since the writing process would not longer change the keys in the loop.

Comment: I understand that. But my question is: Did I fix the problem, or did I make it less frequent?

Comment: I think you fixed it

Comment: what happens if the dictionary changes while `list(my_dict.keys())` is being executed? wouldn't that fail?

Comment: I am also curious about that. We can run some tests.

Comment: I ran some test and did not run into any error. Not sure about the operations behind it though.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is good, because the `list` function consumes the iterator `my_dict.keys()` in one shot, so you don't iterate the dict.

It's the same with `items` and `values`, that can be used for a simpler result:

```
return [v.transform_in_some_way() for k, v in list(my_dict.items())]
```

More simply:

```
return [v.transform_in_some_way() for v in list(my_dict.values())]
```

Comment: this does not answer my question. I'm interested in the internals of `list(my_dict.keys())`

Comment: What exactly does "in one shot" mean?